# How do we know tthe distribution of a variable from a joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is an example from my textbook.

A man throws darts at a circular target with radius 1.
The darts are uniformally spread over the board, meaning that $f_{(x,y)}= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\pi} & \text{if } x^2+y^2\leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

We are interested in the distribution of $U=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$, i.e. the distance from the center of the target.

Using the "Transformation Theorem" we introduce the auxillary variable $V = \arctan(Y/X)$
and get that the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is

$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\begin{cases} \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot u & \text{if } 0 < u < 1, \frac{-\pi}{2} < v < \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

I follow along untill here.

From that it follows, according to the book, that $f_{U}(u)=2u$ for $0<u<1$, and that U and V are independent (and presumably $f_V(v)=\frac{1}{\pi}$).

But how do we know that this is indeed the distribution of the variables, instead of some different distributions that give the same joint distribution (for instance, $f_{U}(u)=\frac{2u}{\pi}$ and $f_V(v)=1$)?

Comment: $f_V(v)=1$ is not a probability density function since it does not integrate to $1$ over $-\frac{\pi}{2} < v \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Similarly $f_U(u)=\frac{2u}{\pi}$  does not integrate to $1$ over $0 \le u \le 1$

Comment: Good point, but how can we still be sure that the answer is the only possible probability density function? And how would one go about to find it?

Comment: To get the marginal densities from the joint density, you try $f_U(u)= \int\limits_v f_{U,V}(u,v) \, dv$ and $f_V(v)= \int\limits_u f_{U,V}(u,v) \, du$